# split "getElementById" into multiple stings based on a character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I split an "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseTex" into different tag ID's based off of a single character "|"?

Here is a picture of what I am looking for:
https://i.ibb.co/njTD8XS/1.png

I tried 2 things but they failed (probably because I don't know what I am doing).

**1st thing I tried - adding ".slice(0, 50)" to the end of " document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText"**

(viewer.js)

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(0,         50);
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(50, 100);
           document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(100, 150);
           document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(150, 200);
           document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(200, 250);
           document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.slice(250, 300);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://f373f63d.ngrok.io/nowplaying.txt?_=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
    xhttp.send();
```

(panel.html)

```
    <div id="demo1"></div>
    <div id="demo2"></div>
    <div id="demo3"></div>
    <div id="demo4"></div>
    <div id="demo5"></div>
    <div id="demo6"></div>
```

This failed  because the text information varies so there is no way to guess the position of the slice. I tried adding a ton of spaces inside the text file of which I am extracting this from to see if that would help but I think xmlhttprequest ingores extra spaces with it imports the data from the website. This means I would need to split based off of a specific character. So I was thinking putting "|" at the end of each line in the text file so I can use that character to split the next line below it.

**2nd thing I tried - I tried using " var fields = ("demo").split(/|/);" to try and grab the demo function or text file I am extracting and split it based on the | character I have on each line.**

(viewer.js)

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   var fields = ("demo").split(/|/);
   var title = fields[0];
   var filename = fields[1];
   var album = fields[2];
   var artists = fields[3];
   var date = fields[4];
   var description = fields[5];
   document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = album;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://f373f63d.ngrok.io/nowplaying.txt?_=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
    xhttp.send();
```

(panel.html)

```
    <div id="demo1"></div>
    <div id="demo2"></div>
```

This failed as I only kept getting the character "m" from "demo2" which makes me thing that it split the word "demo" instead of getting the text file and splitting that from the | characters. If that is the case, how can I make the fields variable have the information of the text file?

I am hoping someone can show me an example of how to use xmlhttprequest with splitting the string into different ID tag elements based of a single character to know where to split. (If that makes any sense).

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Can you `console.log(xhttp.responseText);` inside your `xhttp.onreadystatechange` function and paste it here?

Comment: I don't use nor understand the colsole at all. I need this to show on the front end html not in the console. I apologize if I didn't understand your statement.

Comment: Sure, this will just help us understand what _exactly_ you're getting from server. Add `console.log(xhttp.responseText);` before `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;` and open console (Ctrl+Shift+J) and paste your output here. I'm asking because on your screenshot delimiter is not '|' but ','.

Comment: Ah, understandable. I just did what you requested and toke a snapshot here: https://i.ibb.co/NSc8tg6/2.png

Comment: @mbojko is right, in your second example replace `var fields = ("demo").split(/|/);` with `var fields = ("demo").split('|');` or `var fields = ("demo").split(/\|/);`

Comment: I am sorry I tried that and that doesn't work at all. I said that to @mrbojko but erased my comment as I was going to make another question on here. I just wanted to wait and see if I was interrupting this wrong and I don't believe so.

everytime I have tried that always get a single "m" back. This helps me to see that it is only getting the word "demo" and not my text file. I am sorry but I think I am not explaining this right. I may have to make another question with better pictures or maybe a video.

Answer (score 3):

`|` inside a regexp is just logical *or*. To split by the `|` character, you simply run `myString.split('|')`.

Comment: I am sorry but that does not work for me. I keep getting returned a single "m" back which helps me to see that it is only splitting the word "demo" and not the string. (like I mentioned in the question). Unless I am understanding this wrong which I really hope I am. lol

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue and it toke a little bit of digging around but I used @mbojko idea of the keeping the .split('|') and just had to figure out how to make it work inside the function I already had. I basically added a variable for the http.responseText that gets the text data from the other webserver, then used that variable to do the split based on the | character. Here is the code I changed. Thanks again to @mbojko and @Walk for there time and patience with me.

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
           console.log(xhttp.responseText)
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
           var str = xhttp.responseText;
           var fields = str.split("|");
           var title = fields[0];
           var filename = fields[1];
           var album = fields[2];
           var artists = fields[3];
           var date = fields[4];
           var description = fields[5];
           document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = title;
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = filename;
           document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = album;
           document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = artists;
           document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = date;
           document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = description;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-        anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://f373f63d.ngrok.io/nowplaying.txt?_=" + new         Date().getTime(), true);
    xhttp.send();
```