# how can I use split inside of getElementById("demo") to get multiple id tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a picture of what I am looking for:
https://i.ibb.co/njTD8XS/1.png

Can this be done with `XMLHttpRequest`, `getElementById`, and the `split` command to make multiple id tags based on a character that is the text file.

I just want this:

```
Title - $(title)                    | (The | is the end of the string I want)

Filename - $(filename)                    | (The | is the end of the string I want)

Album - $(album)                    | (The | is the end of the string I want)

Artist - $(artist)                    | (The | is the end of the string I want)

Date - $(date)                    | (The | is the end of the string I want)

Description - $(description)               | (The | is the end of the string I want)
```

I am sorry if I am not explaining myself well. I just want the text to show up on a new line after the | character.

I asked this question 30 minutes ago and the person who answered said, " you simply run myString.split('|')" however **that didn't work**.

I mentioned why it didn't work in the question and no answered why it didn't work. So I apologize if I am repeating myself but no one answered to my issue.

Here is the code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
           var fields = ("demo").split(/|/);
           var title = fields[0];
           var filename = fields[1];
           var album = fields[2];
           var artists = fields[3];
           var date = fields[4];
           var description = fields[5];
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = album;
       }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-    anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://f373f63d.ngrok.io/nowplaying.txt?_=" + new     Date().getTime(), true);
   xhttp.send();
```

I am sliming this down from my last question because it seems that .split() is the answer to what I am looking for but I need this answered or I wont get any further...

**How can I put an id element tag in front of the split() to make it split my lines into multiple ID tags?**

When I asked this last time, I kept getting a single "m" instead of the whole album line. I realized that the issue with the answer I was given is that it only works on stings. **If use var `fields = ("demo").split(/|/)`; it will only pull the word DEMO and not the actual string that was pulled from `XMLHttpRequest`.**

I need `var fields = ("demo").split(/|/);` Where "demo" is this ````` not the word "demo". Does that make sense?

Here is the link to my last post. If it is a true duplicate or the person answered correctly, then explain how it will work for my actual text file that is pulled from `XMLHttpRequest` and not the word "demo".

[Reference to my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776184/split-getelementbyid-into-multiple-stings-based-on-a-character-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment98224995_55776184)

Thank you for your time, and sorry again.

Comment: So we can see what sort of elements and IDs you have, what is your HTML like?

Comment: I actually figured out my own answer! I will be posting it in the other thread I made originally in about 5 minutes. :)

IF someone can delete this question for me, that would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

try to put split with double inverted commas like this
      .split(",");